# MSSQL DB restoration from Azure SQL VM to SQL managed instance via log replay service fails

Tags: database, azure, migration

I was trying to perform an MSSQL DB restoration via Log Replay Service from Azure SQL VM running on SQL 2016 on to SQL managed instance\General Purpose tier. Im using Azure Cli to perform the restoration with continuous mode. It fails with a generic error which doesnt give much information.

[image]

> (InternalServerError) An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: '59763add-7356-4fe4-b797-be1fca9db677'

Can some experts guide me on this error or help me to understand where the issue is?

Comment: Since I cannot see much from the error can you please check here the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/log-replay-service-migrate#functional-limitations) and [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/log-replay-service-migrate#:~:text=check%20for%20the%20most%20common%20issues) for some of the most common issues.

Comment: have you tried using DMS? is there any specific need for you to follow  Log Replay Service method ? was transparent data encryption enabled on source? if yes checkout this [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/managed-instance/sql-server-to-managed-instance-guide#:~:text=corresponding%20certificate%20from%20the%20on-premises%20or%20Azure%20VM%20SQL%20Server%20needs%20to%20be%20migrated%20before%20database%20restore.)

Answer (score 0):

Although going through the snip, I can see no syntactical error please recheck if all the parameters are used correctly refering the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/log-replay-service-migrate#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20an%20example%20of%20starting%20LRS%20in%20continuous%20mode%20by%20using%20the%20Azure%20CLI). Since it appears to be a retryable error try the same CLI command after a few minutes. If the issues persists, [report it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues) or reach out to Microsoft support for a official response.